# How can I test whether a Javascript object has a method with a given name?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following sample:

```
var Container = function(param) {
    this.member = param;
    var privateVar = param;
    if (!Container.prototype.stamp) {  // <-- executed on the first call only
        Container.prototype.stamp = function(string) {
            return privateVar + this.member + string;
        }
    }
}

var cnt = new Container();
```

Is there any way to determine whether the object `cnt` has a method named `stamp` without knowing that it is instantiated from `Container` ?

[image: Another Example]

Comment: I think Visual Studio Watcher is broken :) Because it worked on Firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test for the existence of `stamp` with:

```
if (cnt.stamp) ...
```

or you can check whether it is a function with

```
if (typeof cnt.stamp === 'function') ...
```

Comment: it does work if you test it seperately in a javascript console: `var a = { b: function() {} }; typeof a.b` . Maybe f_SetEk is not a  function? It sais it's an undefined identifier in your image...

Comment: No it is function but in visual studio Watch window it doesn't says it is function. But you are right it is working well in browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```
o = new Object();  
o.prop = 'exists';  
o.hasOwnProperty('prop');             // returns true  
o.hasOwnProperty('toString');         // returns false  
o.hasOwnProperty('hasOwnProperty');   // returns false
```

Comment: I saw hasOwnProperty in some examples that shows  `Array.hasOwnProperty('push')` . But in my example it doesn't work!